# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9"

Tags: java, array, vectores

La tarea es mas extensa y compleja pero en esta etapa lo que debo hacer es elaborar un programa que lea una contraseña y almacene cada caracter en un vector

```java
public class JavaApplication58 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su contraseña");
        String[] Lista=Cadena.split("");
        String Salida="";
        for(int i=0; i<=Lista.length;i++){
            Salida=Lista[i];   
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Salida + " ","matriz leida",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando hagas un bucle que recorra un arreglo, nunca hagas algo así `<=` ya que siempre se cuenta desde 0, por lo que nunca es igual a `length`, `length` es el total de los elementos del 1 al tantos, pero la primera posición es el 0 cuando se accede a los elementos.

Entonces si el arreglo en `length` tiene 9 posiciones, el bucle va del 0 al 8 (9 en total), trata de sacar el `=` del bucle `for`, si no lanzara la excepción.

Comment: amigo, de verdad muuchisimas gracias, me sirvio al 100%!!!!